# Using lookup with an IO list?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I am getting the contents of a file and transforming it into a list of form:

```
[("abc", 123), ("def", 456)]
```

with readFile, lines, and words.

Right now, I can manage to transform the resulting list into type **IO [(String, Int)]**.

My problem is, when I try to make a function like this:

```
check x = lookup x theMap
```

I get this error, which I'm not too sure how to resolve:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[(a0, b0)]'
            with actual type `IO [(String, Int)]'
In the second argument of `lookup', namely `theMap'
```

theMap is essentially this:

```
getLines :: String -> IO [String]
getLines = liftM lines . readFile

tuplify [x,y] = (x, read y :: Int)

theMap = do
    list <- getLines "./test.txt"
    let l = map tuplify (map words list)
    return l
```

And the file contents are:

```
abc 123
def 456
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and or show me a better solution? I just started toying around with monads a few hours ago and am running into a few bumps along the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to "unwrap" `theMap` from IO. Notice how you're already doing this to `getLines` by:

```
do
  list <- getlines
  [...]
  return (some computation on list)
```

So you could have:

```
check x = do
  m <- theMap
  return . lookup x $ m
```

This is, in fact, an antipattern (albeit an illustrative one,) and you would be better off using the functor instance, ie. `check x = fmap (lookup x) theMap`

Comment: Thanks! I should have noticed this :(